# tk.Text is not changing its height, even when propagation is off

Tags: python, python-3.x, textbox, tkinter

I am trying to implement two new GUI subclasses: a `Frame` that can be scrolled and resized dynamically, and a `Text` box that keeps its parent's width but adjusts its height to how many lines of text it has.

The `Frame` seems to work ok but the `Text` is not resizing; when it is first gridded it has a height of 1 and only updates when you resize the Frame (by clicking and dragging the edge). I keep thinking that my code is getting better but I don't know what's going wrong. It seems like the Text class is not updating its height correctly. In `ResizedText.resize()`, when I `config` the container's height to 20, it doesn't update correctly... Before and after that statement, the height is 1, but `cget["height"]` returns 20. Any help on how to make this code better is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ResizedText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.container_container = tk.Frame(parent, bg="blue")
        self.container = tk.Frame(self.container_container, bg="red")
        super().__init__(self.container, *args, **kwargs)
        self.container_container.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.resize)
    def grid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.container_container.grid(*args, **kwargs)
        self.container.grid_propagate(False)
        self.container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        super().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        #self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    def bind(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "add" not in kwargs: kwargs["add"] = True
        super().bind(*args, **kwargs)
    def resize(self, event=None):
        self.container.config(width=self.container_container.winfo_width())
        if self.bbox("end-1c"):
            text_height = (self.bbox("end-1c")[1]+self.bbox("end-1c")[3])+4
            if text_height < 20: text_height = 20
        else: text_height = 20
        self.container.config(height=text_height)
        #after this statement, self.container.winfo_height = 1
        #BUT self.container.cget("height") = 20

class ScrollableFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame)
        yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set, *args,
                **kwargs)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew",)
        yscroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        super().__init__(self.canvas)
        self.grid_propagate(False)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self, anchor="nw")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_main)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_canvas)
    def grid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.grid(*args, **kwargs)
    def resize_canvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def resize_main(self, event):
        self.config(width=event.width, height=self.bbox("all")[3])

GUI = tk.Tk()
GUI.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
GUI.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
f = ScrollableFrame(GUI, bg="brown")
f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
t = ResizedText(f, bg="blue")
t.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Have you tried performing `update_idletasks()` on the text widget after changing its config?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of `resize()` Try `self.update_idletasks()` or `self.update()`

The `update()` command will implement all your changes you made to the widgets, if they didn't happen in the first place.